# Multiple records inserted from one form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form to upload data to multiple MySQL tables and part of it requires four identical sections to upload video location data to one table. All four video sections won't always be filled out sometimes they might all be left blank, then any number up to all four having data. Below is part of the form showing one video location upload, this needs to appear four times on the form:

```
<tr>
    <td>Video 1:</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="location"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Park Video</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="park_id_video" 
                   value="<?=$park_id?>">Park Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ride</td>
        <td>
            <select name="ride_id_video">
            <option value="">Select Ride</option>
            <?php echo $options ?>
            </select>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Below shows the typical insert query I use and will use for this. I have never had to insert multiple records like this though and am not sure about how to do it so all four sets of data can be uploaded in one query. And also so that if any of the four sets of data are blank a blank record won't get inserted.

```
$news_id = $pdo->lastInsertId() ;
    $location = $_POST['headline'];
    $park_id_video = $_POST['park_id_video'];
    $ride_id_video =  $_POST['ride_id_video'];

    $query4 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tpf_videos
                                   (location, park_id, ride_id, news_id) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $query4->execute(array($location, $park_id, $ride_id, $news_id));
```

From what I have read It needs an array but I don't know how to do this. Can somebody help me modify the form and query to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: simply try it. does it work?

Comment: The above would work if it was just for that snippet of form, but I have three other identical snippets that also need to be uploaded via the same query and I don't know know how to separate them out and best pass on the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rename your form's field to like `filed_name[]` and then using a loop you are able to perform multiple insert.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['location']); $i++){
    //Do your insert code. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get an error with that line saying `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')'` any ideas?

Comment: and just to check should the form names be like this `name="url[]"` or `name="url"[]`

Comment: Form's elements names should be as name="someName[]" NOT name="someName"[].

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['location'][$i]); $i++/*expect*/)/*expect*/ {

Comment: Thank you for this, I managed to get it to work. I need to tweak it around a bit to fit my need but this has really helped.

Answer (score 1):

## HTML Example

```
<tr>
    <td>Video 1:</td><td>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Location</td><td><input type="text" name="videos[1][location]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Park Video</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="videos[1][park_id_video]" value="<?=$park_id?>">Park Video</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ride</td>
    <td>
        <select name="videos[1][ride_id_video]">
            <option value="">Select Ride</option>
            <?php echo $options ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Video 2:</td><td>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Location</td><td><input type="text" name="videos[2][location]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Park Video</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="videos[2][park_id_video]" value="<?=$park_id?>">Park Video</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ride</td>
    <td>
        <select name="videos[2][ride_id_video]">
            <option value="">Select Ride</option>
            <?php echo $options ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

## Your backend PHP for a single insert.

```
$news_id = $pdo->lastInsertId() ;
$videos = $_POST['videos'];
$inserts = array();
$args = array();
foreach ($videos as $video) {
    $vid_args = array(
        $video['location'],
        $video['park_id_video'],
        $video['ride_id_video'],
        $news_id
    );

    $inserts[] = "(?,?,?,?)";
    $args = array_merge($args, $vid_args);
}

$sth = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tpf_videos (location, park_id, ride_id, news_id) VALUES ' . implode(',', $inserts));
$sth->execute($args);
```

There may be a syntax error or two in this. I did not run it through PHP. But I believe this is what you were wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>
<td>Video 1:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="location[1]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Park Video</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="park_id_video[1]" 
               value="<?=$park_id?>">Park Video</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ride</td>
    <td>
        <select name="ride_id_video[1]">
        <option value="">Select Ride</option>
        <?php echo $options ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['location']); $i++{
   //Do your insert code.

}
```